# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' while running React Native Project & dependencies of null

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> when i run project for android getting this error

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

sptr@SPTRs-MacBook-Pro first % npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ Ruby - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
```

> sptr@SPTRs-MacBook-Pro first % npx react-native info
> info Fetching system and libraries information...
> System:
> OS: macOS 14.0
> CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
> Memory: 2.04 GB / 16.00 GB
> Shell:
> version: "5.9"
> path: /bin/zsh
> Binaries:
> Node:
> version: 18.18.2
> path: /usr/local/bin/node
> Yarn:
> version: 1.22.19
> path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
> npm:
> version: 9.8.1
> path: /usr/local/bin/npm
> Watchman:
> version: 2023.10.09.00
> path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
> Managers:
> CocoaPods:
> version: 1.13.0
> path: /usr/local/bin/pod
> SDKs:
> iOS SDK:
> Platforms:
> - DriverKit 23.0
> - iOS 17.0
> - macOS 14.0
> - tvOS 17.0
> - watchOS 10.0
> Android SDK:
> API Levels:
> - "33"
> - "33"
> - "33"
> - "34"
> Build Tools:
> - 30.0.0
> - 30.0.3
> - 33.0.0
> - 34.0.0
> System Images:
> - android-33-ext4 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
> - android-33-ext5 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
> - android-33 | Intel x86_64 Atom
> - android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
> - android-33 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
> - android-UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
> Android NDK: Not Found
> IDEs:
> Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
> Xcode:
> version: 15.0/15A240d
> path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
> Languages:
> Java:
> version: 21.0.1
> path: /usr/bin/javac
> Ruby:
> version: 2.6.10
> path: /usr/bin/ruby
> npmPackages:
> "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
> react:
> installed: 18.2.0
> wanted: 18.2.0
> react-native:
> installed: 0.72.6
> wanted: 0.72.6
> react-native-macos: Not Found
> npmGlobalPackages:
> "*react-native*": Not Found
> Android:
> hermesEnabled: true
> newArchEnabled: false
> iOS:
> hermesEnabled: true
> newArchEnabled: false

i dont understand what is exact issue anyone can please help me

run new react-native project not able to understand what is exact issue i am new in react-native

**also added**

> sdk.dir = /Users/sptr/Library/Android/sdk